# angularjs access $scope of Controller from directive using $eval

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying inside a directive to access a method which is defined in the scope of my directive controller

This is a piece of my directive

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('jqmultiselect', function($timeout){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { 
        info: '=info',
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $timeout(function(){
            //simple example
            $(element).click(function(){
                //do something with info
                info = 'test';
                scope.$eval(attrs.customclick);
            });
        });
    }
};
}).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout){
    $scope.myInfo="test";
    $scope.reloadModule = function(info){
        console.log(info);
    };
});
```

What I am trying to do is to call a function named "reloadModule()" in the controller through attribute tag of a HTML element

piece of my HTML code

```
<select
    jqmultiselect 
    info="myInfo" 
    customclick="reloadModule(info)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

More specific example is on the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7j3HV/2/

Do you know how can I make it display the alert with "change ok" inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in your fiddle sample. One is your missing `ng-controller` declaration:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

The other is not exactly and issue but a feature of the "isolated scope" directives, which allows you to use `&` to include methods from a parent controller.

Something like:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('jqmultiselect', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { 
            info: '=info',
            customclick:"&"
        },
...
```

This allows you to invoke the method inside your directive as simple as `scope.customclick();`

Regarding your second question, how to update a var from my directive, here [fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3J5L4/6/):

```
scope.$apply(function () {
   scope.info = "change ok";
});
```

Here is the corrected version:

http://jsfiddle.net/3J5L4/5/

Comment: Please do not forget to mark this as your answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Sorry for the error, I think you answered just before we edit the jsfiddle ! Thanks for the `&` info, however I still can't make it update my 'info' data in the parent scope. See this example updated with `&` : http://jsfiddle.net/MmDh3/1/ (I'd like to log "change ok") Any idea ?

Comment: Yes but why $scope.myInfo doesn't change ? ({{myInfo}} stays at 'test' instead of 'change ok' ) Can we modify its value in the controller scope from the directive ? See this jsfiddle, maybe it's a better example : http://jsfiddle.net/3YxbY/1/

Comment: It is $scope.info in your directive and just info